# Cronjob timing out with internal server error

Tags: php, bash, zend-framework, timeout, cron

My hosting provider only allows me to run a cronjob every 2 hours. Since I need it to run every second, I've made a page that will run for 2 hours. Also, I developed with ZF; so the page needs to be bootstrapped, which means the cronjob needs to call a web address.

So far my bash script runs every two hours:

```
#!/bin/bash

wget "http://www.mysite.co.za/ajax/cron"
```

However, it stops after a few minutes with the following error:

```
--2011-02-04 09:32:32--  http://www.mysite.co.za/ajax/cron
Resolving www.mysite.co.za... 123.40.97.157
Connecting to www.mysite.co.za|123.40.97.157|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 500 Internal Server Error
2011-02-04 09:37:33 ERROR 500: Internal Server Error
```

I don't know much about cronjobs/bash scripts, but I think it's timing out? Can anyone confirm this? If so, I'll look into curl_mutl_init to send a response back and keep the process alive at the same time - I don't think I'll have access to process control functions.

If anyone has any tips/advice, please don't hesitate.

Comment: Do you have access to the error-logfile of your (Apache) webserver? The specific error should be logged.

Comment: If you are running the job once a second, it is very likely that you have multiple processes doing the same exact thing at any given time, since a job could conceivably take more than a second to complete. Are you managing locking correctly?

Comment: @initall, no, there is no such logfile. I also don't have permission to change apache settings.

Comment: @tim, I'm not too sure what you mean by locking. The process is extremely small, taking no more than 100ms. I currently run one function looping; doing the check and then sleeping for 900ms. I just need it to do it for 2 hours/7200 times consecutively without interruption.

Answer (score 1):

Several comments observations:

**1. Bootstrapping**

It is not the case that a ZF task using the bootstrap needs to come via an HTTP request. You can run command-line tasks that use your bootstrap.

In your `my_script.php` - typically placed in directory `scripts` or in `application/scripts` - you can start with much of the same content as your web app's `index.php` file: check/set `include_path`, check/set `APPLICATION_ENV`, check/set `APPLICATION_PATH`, and instantiate your `Zend_Application` object.

The only difference is that you call `$application->bootstrap()`, but *don't* proceed along to `$application->run()`. In fact, since some of the bootstrapped resources might be needed only for the *web* app, you can call:

```
$application     
    ->bootstrap('necessaryResource1')  
    ->bootstrap('necessaryResource2')
    ->bootstrap('necessaryResource3');`
```

so you don't bootstrap resources you don't need.

Then go on to perform the specifics of your task.

**2. Command line**

If you wish to design your script to accept parameters, you can use `Zend_Console_GetOpt`. It's pretty cool.

**3. Once-per-second?**

Of course, I don't know your use-case or your specific need, but running a job once per second sure sounds like a lot to me. Is it possible to put some of these tasks into a queue and consume the queue with a frequency allowable under your hosting?

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for you detailed answer. I'm not too concerned about what happens/bootstrapping when I call the script, since it's only called once and I repeat the function 7200 times in the 2 hours. No parameters necessary, though it sounds good. I just need to fool the server into thinking it's finished while it isnt'.

Comment: David's answer is pretty well done, i would add that the vast majority of servers have an execution time limit on PHP, often around 5 minutes (since 5 minutes is a very long time for a single script to run).

Comment: @Tjorriemorrie: Indeed, both ideas: (1) a very long-running script (say, two hours) and (2) a high-frequency script (say, once per minute), strike me as likely to be problematic, especially on a shared host. Are you sure you need that kind of instant feedback? If the intent is provide create some kind of up-to-the-second environment for your standard requests, why couldn't the data they need be computed during the request itself?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a cron that needs to be run every second, It might be better to use page loads to fire off your script.  So each time someone requests a new page, it would run the script.  Cron isn't capable of running on intervals any less than a minute anyway.

You can also write a php script that has the following code

continuous.php:

```
while(true){
     sleep(1); //pause 1 second
     exec("wget http://youraddress.com");
}
```

bash script to see if your php script is running

checkContinuous.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
#check if script is running
CHECK=`ps -ef |grep continuous.php`;
if [ -z "$CHECK" ]; then
#script not running, start it
   php /path/to/continuous.php& ; #start script and fork it
fi;
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Your function is kind of what I'm doing. I do need it to run every second; and not more than once a second, therefore I can't rely on requests. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: You can just put the above code in a php file, and run it on your host commandline.  Then setup another script to check if your php file is still running, and restart it if not.  That way it will get started if it dies somewhere in the 2 hour space that your host allows.

Answer (score 0):

whatever backend server side script you are using, ask it to run for infinite amount of time OR ignore user abort.

Your webserver might have some settings to increase time out period too.. (Apache has it, I've used this feature )

Comment: If he can only run a cron once every two hours, then I doubt he can change the timeout settings on the server.

Comment: @Aatch: you think he's got no access to server configs ? 
isn't there a way to set it from php itself ? :)